# get all the files to be compiled from .config file

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, android

I have an old kernel and I didn't manage to get the toolchain to cross compile it. So I decided to upgrade this version of the kernel.  My question is how can I know all the files(source, blobs and probably scripts ) that will be integrated in the final kernel image bzImage ?

Can I deduce this from .config/Makefiles ?